# Find button clicked event's cause in WindowProc

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm learning Windows-based GUI in C++, so I set up a simple project with a window with inside a button (and I'm able to detect when this button is clicked).
Now, in my window's `WindowProc`, I'd like to find the "cause" that fired the WM_COMMAND, with cause I mean that I want to find if the button was clicked with the mouse, or if the user set it on focus and then pressed Enter(or Space)
Here is a piece of the `WindowProc`:

```
    int UControl::WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        OutputDebugStringNewLine((UWindowsDebugHelper::GetMessageString(message) + TEXT(" ") + this->GetType()).c_str()); //This writes on the VS Output window the code of the message as string, for example it writes "WM_COMMAND" when it is received, instead of "273"
        switch (message)
        {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        case WM_COMMAND:
            if(lParam != 0)
            {
                if(HIWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED)
                {
                    UControl* ctrl = this->FindControl((HWND)lParam);
                    __raise ctrl->Click(ctrl, UEventArgs::Empty);
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        if(this->_nativeWndProc != NULL)
            return this->_nativeWndProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        else
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

HIWORD(wParam) is BN_CLICKED when I click the button with mouse, but it is BN_CLICKED also when I "click" it with the Space key.

How can I distinguish the event cause?

Comment: You should never need to know this. There are plenty of other ways to invoke a button click, FWIW.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I was trying to reproduce the .NET Form behavior and I noticed that the button click event contains this kind of info. `void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` when the button is clicked using the mouse, `e` is an instance of `MouseEventArgs`, otherwise it's `EventArgs.Empty`

Comment: WPF or WinForms, and why would anyone care?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan WinForms. Why would anyone care? I don't really know, I was just trying to figure out the mechanism used by WinForm to get this info

Comment: I don't think WinForms uses a Win32 button does it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That's a good point, in order to reproduce the WinForm's behavior, I'll start by subclassing the Button and get the infos there. Thanks

Comment: @David: Windows Forms encapsulate native controls (in contrast to WPF, for example). A standard [ButtonBase](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ButtonBase.cs,fe9dda280e95f0a1) control sets the `UserMouse` [ControlStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlstyles.aspx) in its c'tor. I would assume that it does so, to produce the `MouseEventArgs` for button clicks. I would also assume that `EventArgs.Empty` is used for **everything** else, not just keyboard. If true, this would be pretty useless.

Comment: @IInspectable I think that in the case of a button, the WinForms button is not Win32 BUTTON.

Comment: @David: You are right. A Windows Forms `Button` control encapsulates a native Win32 custom control (window class: WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.141b42a_r10_ad1), not a Win32 BUTTON control.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I distinguish the event cause?

`BN_CLICKED` does not provide that information.  You would have to track the `WM_LBUTTON(DOWN/UP)` and `WM_KEY(DOWN/UP)` messages separately to figure out what is going on.  But that only helps you distinguish between mouse/keyboard clicks.  As DavidHeffernan said, there are other ways to click on buttons, and/or simulate `BN_CLICKED` directly, without going through the mouse/keyboard at all.